# Eliminate zeroed values in an array with dataweave function

Tags: arrays, dataweave, mulesoft

***In this array of a list of devices, you would need to delete from the array when any item was zeroed out***

```js
[
    {
        "valueTotal": "6.50"
    },
    {
        "bread": "001",
        "value": "3.00"
    },
    {
        "milk": "002",
        "value": "3.50"
    },
    {
        "coffe": "003",
        "value": "0.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add the expected output as well, so that it might help others to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend to remove the items in the input, whose "value" field is 0 and then get the totalValue. Here is a quick one I have come up with(could be improved).

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

//filter the items whose value is zero
var filteredPayload= ((payload [-1 to 1] map (item1, index1) -> 
{
      (if (item1.value as Number != 0)  (item1) else null)
}) filter  ($ != {}))

// get the totalValue from the filteredPayload
var totalFilteredPayload = filteredPayload reduce ($.value + $$.value)

---
// simply add both the arrays
filteredPayload ++ [{  "valueTotal": totalFilteredPayload as String }]
```

Comment: You do not need to recalculate the total after removing zero values 

Answer (score 0):

If by "zeroed out" you mean `value` = 0 it is just a basic [`filter`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-filter) operation

```js
payload filter ($.valueTotal? or ($.value as Number != 0))
```

The condition `$.valueTotal?` is to make the object with `valueTotal` pass the check. And the other one is for the `value` itself.